# I'm getting "undefined" when trying to get ETH last price from CMC

Tags: javascript, ajax, solidity

I have a small price widget that gives me the last price of ethereum on CMC

```
<script>
  $.ajax({

    url : 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/',
    type : 'GET',
    data : {
        'numberOfWords' : 10
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
        console.log('Error by getting the ETH price');
    }
  });
  </script>
```

The url comes with all of this data

```
[
{
"id": "ethereum",
"name": "Ethereum",
"symbol": "ETH",
"rank": "2",
"price_usd": "138.566166052",
"price_btc": "0.01850224",
"24h_volume_usd": "7342353696.2",
"market_cap_usd": "15125162393.0",
"available_supply": "109154802.0",
"total_supply": "109154802.0",
"max_supply": null,
"percent_change_1h": "-0.34",
"percent_change_24h": "2.83",
"percent_change_7d": "3.31",
"last_updated": "1578254485"
}
]
```

My console.log output says undefined when I do for price_usd:

```
console.log(data[4]);
```

how can i access the price_usd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `data` variable you have an array which contains an object with its properties. To access that object you can use `data[0]` which is the first element of the array. Then the properties by like `data[0].propertyName`.

If you have only 1 element in the array you can do like: `data[0].price_usd`. But is worth to check if it has values or not like: `data && data.length > 0 ? data[0].price_usd : undefined`.

Like the following:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "ethereum",
    "name": "Ethereum",
    "symbol": "ETH",
    "rank": "2",
    "price_usd": "138.566166052",
    "price_btc": "0.01850224",
    "24h_volume_usd": "7342353696.2",
    "market_cap_usd": "15125162393.0",
    "available_supply": "109154802.0",
    "total_supply": "109154802.0",
    "max_supply": null,
    "percent_change_1h": "-0.34",
    "percent_change_24h": "2.83",
    "percent_change_7d": "3.31",
    "last_updated": "1578254485"
}];

const result = data && data.length > 0 ? data[0].price_usd : undefined;
console.log(result);
```

You can access with `data[]` array elements, not properties in this case:

```js
const data = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
console.log(data[4]);
```

Or even better example, just think about the following:

```js
const data = [{price_usd: 123}];
const firstElementOfArray = data[0];

console.log({firstElementOfArray});
console.log('price_usd', firstElementOfArray.price_usd);
```

I suggest to read for better understanding:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

I hope that helps!

Comment: perfect, it works, but may i know why you access the data in the array the way you do?
i thought console.log(data[4]); was the proper way

4 for being the 5th element in an array

Comment: @yappytwan I have extended my answer, I hope that clarifies.